# Trouble understanding bug leetcode problem 202 Happy Numbers Python

Tags: python

Hey all just started practicing leetcode problems in python and was confused as to why my code wasn't working. I seem to be having a problem with undefined name when I try to run my code. Appreciate the help. Getting runtime error saying that n = solvingThisThing(n) is not defined

```
class Solution:

  def solvingThisThing(n: int):

    sum_of_squares = 0
    digit = 0
    while(n!=0):
        digit = n % 10
        sum_of_squares += (digit * digit)
        n = n // 10
    return sum_of_squares

  def isHappy(n: int):

    past_nums = set()
    past_nums.add(n)
    
    while(True):
        if(n == 1):
            return True
        n = solvingThisThing(n)
        
        if n in past_nums:
            return False
        else:
            past_nums.add(n)
    return False
```

Comment: Hey, could you add the problem and the error you are getting?

Comment: just added thanks!

Comment: solvingThisThing is part of the solution class, so you have to run it from that context (i.e. Solution.solvingThisThing)

Answer (score 0):

Since the solvingThisThing method is a part of the Solution class, you have to run it from the solution class.

```
n=Solution.solveThisThing(n)
```

should work instead of

```
n=solveThisThing(n)
```